# Add file at the root of mapped domain in multisite

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping

I have a multisite (let's call it multisite.com) with subdomains and domain mapping.

One of the subdomains (id 11) is mapped to domain.com, on which I am using AdSense.

I just got a notification from Google that I need to add a file ads.txt at the root of domain.com.

I added the file at the root of the main multisite.com domain, but obviously, when I try domain.com/ads.txt I get a 404, not found.

I also uploaded the file on the uploads folder of the subdomain, which is multisite.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/11

But this is not the solution either.

Is there any way I can upload a file to be found at a root of a subdomain mapped to a domain.com?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to add the file ads.txt at the root of a mapped domain is to install a plugin to handle that. In my case, I searched the plugins directory for Ads.txt.

I have installed a plugin called Ads.txt Manager. After installation to to plugin's settings and paste the text that you have in the Ads.txt file. Click save, and you'll see that the ads.txt file is now visible on domain.com - the mapped domain.